# edit wireshark cap file: change the crc value to be bad

Tags: networking, wireshark, ethernet

I want to generate a cap file with bad CRC packets using wireshark.
I recorded the traffic I want but:
1. I don't see the CRC in the wireshark GUI and couldn't find where to enable this view
2. I cant find a way to "corrupt" the CRC of all packets in the cap file

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer I got in the wireshark support forum:

Assuming you mean the CRC of the ethernet frame, then you're out of luck with a normal NIC. Most NIC (drivers) strip it before passing the packet to the system. That means wireshark (actually libpcap/WinPcap which does the capturing for wireshark) does not get to see the CRC.

There are capture cards that do not strip the CRC, but I have not used them myself so I can't advice you on that.

http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/20862/how-to-display-the-packets-crc-in-the-gui-and-how-to-edit-crc-with-bad-value